# Taking response from Node.js in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am trying to fetch data from Mongodb and i want that data to show up on my web page.The problem is i don't know how to send the whole fetched object to a specific port (the response) so that i'll be able to fetch it from Angular and how will i be able to access data from Angular

Fetching data from Mongodb

```
app.get('/api/getdata',async (req,res) =>
{
const {value} = req.body
const resp=await person.find({value})
if(!resp){
console.log('not found')
}
else{
 //this needs to be done
}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, have a look at [express API reference](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html)

then your code would look like :

```
app.get('/api/getdata', async (req,res) => {
  const {value} = req.body
  const resp = await person.find({value})
  if (!resp) {
    res.status(404).send('not found')
  }else{
    // give your data to express response to the http request
    res.json(resp); // or res.send(resp);
  }
});
```